# NextJS Build Error: Failed to compile| static/media/thread.2465a67c.js from Terser | 'import', and 'export' cannot be used outside of module code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I working on a NextJS 14 project, and it's working fine during development but while running `next build` I am getting the following error:

```
> npm run build                                                                                                                                                                             
> bookie@0.1.0 build
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
   - Environments: .env.local

   Creating an optimized production build ...
Failed to compile.

static/media/thread.2465a67c.js from Terser
  x 'import', and 'export' cannot be used outside of module code
   ,-[1:1]
 1 | import { Buffer } from "node:buffer";
   : ^^^^^^
 2 | import crypto from "node:crypto";
 3 | import { parentPort } from "node:worker_threads";
 4 | parentPort.on("message", (message)=>{
   `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to parse input file
    1: Syntax Error
Error:
  x 'import', and 'export' cannot be used outside of module code
   ,-[1:1]
 1 | import { Buffer } from "node:buffer";
   : ^^^^^^
 2 | import crypto from "node:crypto";
 3 | import { parentPort } from "node:worker_threads";
 4 | parentPort.on("message", (message)=>{
   `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to parse input file
    1: Syntax Error


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

I managed to pinpoint the particular package that was causing this error during the build. When i remove the code related to the package build command finishes without issues.

I am using [@ctrl/qbittorrent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ctrl/qbittorrent?activeTab=readme) package in my next project in an API route. The code for that is as follows:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { createClient } from "@/libs/supabase/server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import parseTorrent from "parse-torrent";
import qbitClient from "@/libs/qbittorrent";
import type { BookInfo } from "@/types/api";
import Queue from "@/libs/bullmq/queue";

const TORRENT_DOWNLOAD_URL = (torrentId: string) =>
  `https://www.zz12.d2/x24x/download.php/${torrentId}`;

type TorrentDownload = {
  torrentBuffer: Buffer;
  infoHash: string | undefined;
};

// Download torrent file from the given URL and return the buffer and infoHash
async function downloadTorrent(bookData: BookInfo): Promise<TorrentDownload> {
  const downloadUrl = TORRENT_DOWNLOAD_URL(bookData.dl);
  const { data: torrentBuffer } = await axios.get(downloadUrl, {
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36",
    },
  });
  const { infoHash } = await parseTorrent(torrentBuffer);
  return { torrentBuffer, infoHash };
}

// Add torrent to the client if it doesn't exist already else skip adding
async function addTorrentToClient(torrentBuffer: Buffer, infoHash: string) {
  const getTorrentByHash = await qbitClient.listTorrents({
    hashes: [infoHash],
  });
  if (getTorrentByHash.length === 0) {
    await qbitClient.addTorrent(torrentBuffer);
  }
}

// Add book to the user's list and start downloading the torrent
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const supabase = createClient(cookies());
    const { data: userData } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
    const userId = userData?.user?.id as string;
    const bookData: BookInfo = await req.json();
    const { torrentBuffer, infoHash } = await downloadTorrent(bookData);

    const { data: isBookInDB } = await supabase
      .from("books")
      .select("*")
      .eq("hash", infoHash as string)
      .eq("user_id", userId);

    if (isBookInDB && isBookInDB.length > 0) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "Book already exists in your list" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    await addTorrentToClient(torrentBuffer, infoHash as string);

    const { data } = await supabase
      .from("books")
      .insert({
        title: bookData.title,
        hash: infoHash,
        narrators: Object.values(bookData.narrator_info),
        authors: Object.values(bookData.author_info),
        file_type: bookData.filetype,
        type: bookData.main_cat === 13 ? "Audiobook" : "eBook",
        status: "ADDED TO LIST",
        size: bookData.size,
        user_id: userId,
      })
      .select();

    await Queue.add("download", { infoHash, userId });

    return NextResponse.json({
      data,
      message: "Book added successfully to the list and download started",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Error handling the request" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

If i comment the inner body of `addTorrentToClient` function from above code then build command succeeds without any issues.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: For the time being, I ended up removing the conflicting code and package for the API route and moved into bullmq queue processing worker.